# Centering makes the table narrow

Tags: css

I am centering a table as follows:

```
<div class="center-box">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1>Some text.</h1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h1>Why does this line get wrapped? Why does this line get wrapped?</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.center-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

For some reason, the table no longer occupies 100% of the viewport width. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Luskhpb7/).

**UPDATE 1**: Following the reply suggesting to use flex, I produced the [linked example](http://jsfiddle.net/j0a6z3sm/), for which that approach is not working so far.

Comment: your table has no set `width` or `min-width`...

Comment: @vsync Using `table {width: 100vw;}` makes the table display flush to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've halved the available width of the table's container by setting left to 50%. Right computes to 0. So what's remaining between left and right is just the other 50%.

Solution is to use a better centering method, like flexbox.

```css
.center-box {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-box">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1>Some text.</h1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h1>Why does this line get wrapped? Why does this line get wrapped?</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the post with an example for which this fails...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it doesn't fail, in the new example you provided you are setting 20%/80% the widths so what are you expecting to get? add borders to all the elements to see that everything is centred

Comment: @TemaniAfif I expect the table as a unit, not the individual elements, to be centered with respect to the viewport width. Why is my expectation wrong? How exactly do I fix this example to have the table as a whole centered?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning your table *is* centered. Add a border to it and you will see how it's centered

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right. But what determines the width of the table? How do I set it?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it's based on the table content